# Ability to create users only in a specific AAD group

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a way in Azure Active Directory to grant a user the ability to create users in a specific group but nowhere else?

For instance, Sam is the project manager for project wingbat. I create a group named wingbats, make Sam the owner of it and allow him to invite users to that group or add native users to that group but nowhere else in the AD.

I would like to know if this is achievable using custom RBAC roles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-create-custom and if yes, can you share any custom script for the same?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, if Sam is just a normal user, that is to say without any administrator role, and after you add him as a specific group owner, he will only be able to add users to this group. He does not have any permissions to add users to other groups.

I think your description has met your needs. There is no need to use custom RBAC roles.

Correct me if there is any misunderstanding.